# userForm value not in range

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to validate the length of ID value in userForm in Angular14, I tried for

```
if(this.userForm.value.id.length < 6 || this.userForm.value.id.length >9){
      console.log("length error")
    }
```

But this is not giving the expected result. the above snippet is working for `!= and =` only.

How can I validate this value for the range.

Adding the .ts and .html snippets for the better understanding.
component.ts

```
userSubmit(){
    console.log(this.userForm.get('image').value);
    console.log(this.userForm.value);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', this.images);
    formData.append('id', this.userForm.value.id);
    formData.append('des', this.userForm.value.des);
    formData.append('name', this.userForm.value.name);
    
    if(this.userForm.value.id.length < 6 || this.userForm.value.id.length > 9){
      console.log("length error")
}
```

component.html

```
<div class="container">

    <div *ngIf="errorMsg" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>{{errorMsg}}</strong> 
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>

      

      <form [formGroup]="userForm"  >

    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-2" >
        <label>Employee ID:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control"  formControlName="id"  [(ngModel)]="id">
    </div>
        
    
    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-2" *ngIf="!getParamId" >
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" [disabled]="!name || !des ||!photo||!id" (click)="userSubmit()">
            Submit!!
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 mt-2" *ngIf="getParamId" >
        <button class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"  (click)="userUpdate()" >
            Update
        </button>
    </div>

</form>


</div>
```

Comment: Does your question solved?

Comment: No, I am still stuck

Comment: Anyway what is `id` type? Is it string? If yes, you shouldn't use `type="number` for the input element. Use `type="text"` (default) for the string. While you may apply `Validator.minLength()` and `Validator.maxLength()` to validate the value is in within the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you are performing the validation for `id` with the length within a range.

The problem is currently your **`id` is not a `string`**, but it is a `number`.

```
<input type="number" class="form-control"  formControlName="id"  [(ngModel)]="id">
```

Hence you can't use `.length` as this property doesn't exist in the `number` value.

---

1. Change the `<input>` element from `type="number"` to `type="text"` or without `type`. (By default `type` is `text`).
2. Since you are using the Reactive form, you don't need the `[(ngModel)]`.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="id" />
```

3. Add `Validators.minLength()` and `Validators.maxLength()` validators to `id` form control.

```js
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

this.userForm = this.fb.group({
  id: [
    '',
    [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(9)],
  ],
  // Following controls
});
```

Note: If you want the `id` input to be numeric characters, you need `Validators.pattern()`:

```js
Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')
```

Or validate with the length as well, so the `Validators.minLength()` and `Validators.maxLength()` can be omitted.

```js
Validators.pattern('[0-9]{6,9}')
```

4. To disable the submit button when there is any control(s) that failed the validation:

```
<button
  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
  [disabled]="idHasError /* or other form controls */"
  (click)="userSubmit()"
>
  Submit!!
</button>
```

And implementing the getter.

```js
get idHasError() {
  return this.userForm.controls.id.errors;
}
```

Implement the getter method(s) for the rest form control(s) to return a boolean value that the form control has `errors` or not.

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oe7yph?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, your answer worked. But can't it be done like, if I am having multiple fields and I am enabling the submit button if all the fields are entered(no matter what they have filled). And on clicking the submit button it should flash an error, in my case something like `"The ID should be between 6-9 digits only"`. Also I do have other fields like name and all which are also behaving the same way but should pop the error while clicking the submit button like `"Only alphabets are allowed"`. I am looking for a solution which is validation `onClick` event.